# AVplayer not showing in ScrollView after 2-3 times

Tags: iphone, ios, scrollview, avplayer

I am adding multiple AVPlayer objects in a scrollview. For the first time this is working fine but as i go back to my previous view and come back again i am not able to see AVPlayer objects in scrollView.

I need as matrix of multiple AVPlayer to show thumbnails of my videos.

Please help me asap

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @please describe your question neatly and with some sort of code.

Comment: As I already mentioned in my question that i want to create a matrix( 3 X 3) of videos. Suppose i have three videos, i added this videos using AVPlayer to my view in a single row on some view. Now i navigate to another view and again come back to the matrix view i found that there are 2 videos out of three. There is no error in my code and running properly.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem and after a lot of searching discovered that the AVPLayerItem object causes this issue.

Basically when the AVPlayer items go offscreen you need to make sure everything is released properly, and then recreate everything when they come back on screen.

As part of the release process, include the line:

```
[AVPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:nil];
```

That sorted a very similar issue for me.

Comment: This just saved my app!

Comment: This worked for me too, but is there any official Apple response to this?

Answer (score 0):

```
[AVPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:nil];
```

also solves my problem of cannot releasing current player item immediately. (can't manually do that because it's retained by the class..)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you get 10 AVPlayers to play simultaneously, inside the same scrollView, each and every time you scroll it:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  VideoWall
//
//  Created by James Alan Bush on 6/13/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 James Alan Bush. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

static NSString *kCellIdentifier = @"Cell Identifier";

@interface ViewController () {
    dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueueLocal;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (id)initWithCollectionViewLayout:(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)layout
{
    if (self = [super initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout])
    {
        [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
        dispatchQueueLocal = dispatch_queue_create( "local session queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT );
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [self.collectionView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.width, AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.height)];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDataSource>

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.assetsFetchResults.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = (UICollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
        cell.contentView.layer.sublayers = nil;
        dispatch_release(dispatchQueueLocal);
    }];
    dispatch_retain(dispatchQueueLocal);
    dispatch_async( dispatchQueueLocal, ^{
        [self drawPlayerLayerForCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    });
    [CATransaction commit];

    return cell;
}

- (void)drawPlayerLayerForCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    void (^drawPlayerLayer)(UICollectionViewCell*, NSIndexPath*) = ^(UICollectionViewCell* cell, NSIndexPath* indexPath) {
        [AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.imageManager requestPlayerItemForVideo:AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.assetsFetchResults[indexPath.item] options:nil resultHandler:^(AVPlayerItem * _Nullable playerItem, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if(![[info objectForKey:PHImageResultIsInCloudKey] boolValue]) {
                    AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:[AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem]];
                    [playerLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
                    [playerLayer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
                    [playerLayer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
                    [playerLayer setFrame:cell.contentView.bounds];

                    [cell.contentView.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
                    [(AVPlayer *)playerLayer.player play];

                } else {
                    [AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.imageManager requestImageForAsset:AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.assetsFetchResults[indexPath.item]
                                                                          targetSize:CGSizeMake(AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.flowLayout.itemSize.width, AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.flowLayout.itemSize.height)
                                                                         contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
                                                                             options:nil
                                                                       resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
                                                                           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                                               cell.contentView.layer.contents = (__bridge id)result.CGImage;
                                                                           });
                                                                       }];
                }
            });
        }];
    };
    drawPlayerLayer(cell, indexPath);
}

@end
```

Here's the AppDelegate implementation file:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  VideoWall
//
//  Created by James Alan Bush on 6/13/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 James Alan Bush. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

+ (AppDelegate *)sharedAppDelegate
{
    return (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch

    self.width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width / 2.0;
    self.height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height / 4.0;

    self.window                    = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = [self viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController.view = self.viewController.view;


    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (ViewController *)viewController {
    ViewController *c = self->_viewController;
    if (!c) {
        c = [[ViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:[self flowLayout]];
        [c.view setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        self->_viewController = c;
    }
    return c;
}

- (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)flowLayout {
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *v = self->_flowLayout;
    if (!v) {
        v = [UICollectionViewFlowLayout new];
        [v setItemSize:CGSizeMake(AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.width, AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.height)];
        [v setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
        [v setMinimumLineSpacing:0.0];
        [v setMinimumInteritemSpacing:0.0];
        [v setEstimatedItemSize:CGSizeMake(AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.width, AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.height)];
        self->_flowLayout = v;
    }
    return v;
}

- (PHCachingImageManager *)imageManager {
    PHCachingImageManager *i = self->_imageManager;
    if (!i) {
        i = [[PHCachingImageManager alloc] init];
        self->_imageManager = i;
    }
    return i;
}

- (PHFetchResult *)assetsFetchResults {
    PHFetchResult *i = self->_assetsFetchResults;
    if (!i) {
        PHFetchResult *smartAlbums = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeSmartAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeSmartAlbumVideos options:nil];
        PHAssetCollection *collection = smartAlbums.firstObject;
        if (![collection isKindOfClass:[PHAssetCollection class]])
            return nil;
        PHFetchOptions *allPhotosOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
        allPhotosOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO]];
        i = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:collection options:allPhotosOptions];
        self->_assetsFetchResults = i;
    }
    return i;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

These are the only two files you need; no NIB/XIB.